# Specific Big O Questions

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

We're getting into Big O in my CS degree and am having a difficult time understanding it.  There's two problems I'd like to post, one I tried to complete on my own and another I'm not sure how to start.  Would it be possible for a member to tell me if my first one is correct or incorrect and maybe point me in a direction for understanding the second one?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
a)
    E(n) ≤ 5n^2 + 9n^3, then E(n) = O(?)

    Guess: O(n^3)

    Proof:

    9n^3 + 5n^2 <= c*n^3, where c = 10 and n > 1,
    Therefore, E(n) = O(n^3)

b) 

    E(n) ≤ 8n*sqrt(n) + 100n log2(n), then E(n) = O(?) .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) 
For n = 2, 
9*8 + 5*4 = 92 > 10 * 8 = 80. (n > 1 is incorrect)
You should solve for an n explicitly.

b) 
Should be order of O(n^3/2). Check with a large number such as 2^50. log(n) grows much more slowly than n^1/2.

Comment: No, you need a larger 'n' after which the equation always holds. 9n^3 + 5n^2 < 10n^3 => n > 5

Comment: Oops, I see my mistake.  It seems that plugging in values of n all the way up to 5 makes the statement incorrect, until I reach 6.  So it would be correct when c = 10 and n = 6?

Comment: Thank you, I'm unsure why we need to do this?  Will there ever be cases when the big O of a function isn't the largest term in the original function?

Comment: I guess I'm still a little confused on part b.  Part a makes total sense, but with b, how do I find a specific value of N in order to prove it?  I'm assuming I need a constant c of at least 9, since the coefficient in the original term (8n^(3/2)) is 8, so I assume I need to use the constant 9, but is there any good way of finding the n value at this point?  The values at which the statement become true are extremely large, not sure how to pinpoint that number.

Comment: Are there any issues with choosing a C value thats extremely high so that we don't have to calculate a very high N value?  For example, in problem 2, if I let c = 9, we have to use numbers extremely high for n to satisfy the definition, but if I use something huge for C, like 100, I only have to get to about 27 before the definition is true.  Is there anything wrong with this logic?